# How to reverse the words in the string in automation anywhere

Tags: automationanywhere

I am trying to reverse the string For Example string s= "Hello Robot Process Automation" will be changed to String s="Automation Process Robot Hello" in automation anywhere.

I tried below steps:-

1. Reverse the sentence(it reverses the words and alphabets in words as well).
   2.Split the sentence and put into list variable
2. used loop and in same loop i reversed again the alphabets so now the sentence will be like "Automation" "Process" "Robot" "Hello" into one list
   4 I am not getting next step after this(joining of these words).

Please help.

Answer (score 2):

For reversing the string as per above requirement, below are the steps:

1. Create a variable for storing the reversed string called `vReversedString`
2. Reverse the given string i.e from above string the output should be `noitamotuA ssecorP toboR olleH`
3. Split the reversed string by space deliminator and store in `my-list-variable`
4. Loop through `my-list-variable`
5. Reverse the each element through the loop. For example, In this case the first element is `noitamotuA` by reversing this you'll be getting `Automation` as an output, store it to system variable `clipboard` or create a new variable to hold each element.
6. Concatenate and store to `vReversedString` = `$vReversedString$` `$clipboard$`

[image: Code snippet for reverse the words in a string]

Comment: Thanks Vijay for your help..I was not getting the 7th step that was variable operation to convert the list values into variables. It is clear now.

Comment: @aby191 could you mind to accept the answer, if you found given solution solves the problem.